# How to limit the scope in diagflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, diagflow

I'm trying to figure out how to have an agent answer questions regarding different locations.  
We have a business with several locations and I'd like to have one chat bot answer questions about each location.  For example,I will have the same bot installed on each locations website. when a user asks the bot, ***"what are your opening hours?"***, ***how can I let the bot know which location the user is requesting information about?***

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Create different Dialogflow agents for each location
2. When you integrate with each website include [payload information](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#QueryParameters.FIELDS.payload) about the location in your detectIntent API request and handle the payload information in your [fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) to respond contextually.